# Vue3/Pinia: Using Pinia store inside a composable throws TypeError within pinia core code

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, composable

We are running a SPA compiled with vite and Vue3.
As soon as we call the useStore() function inside a composable, we encounter a Type Error in the pinia code:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_s')
```

It happens in the pinia core code

We can use this store without issues anywhere else in our app (SPA).
It seems that the composables are run too early and create this error because the pinia instance is not ready yet (similar issue here, albeit with SSG: https://github.com/antfu/vite-ssg/issues/103 )

1. Create a dummy store
   import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import type { Ref } from 'vue'

export const useTestStore = defineStore('customer-portal', () => {
  console.log('Defining Teststore...')
  const test: Ref<string> = ref('')
  return {
    test,
  }
})
```

2. Create a composable using this store:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useTestStore } from '@/vue/store/test'
const store = useTestStore()
```

3. Use theat composable in a component (import store and call useTestStore())

Comment: Your question is hard to answer. More context is needed. Provide minimal reproducible example using services like CodeSandbox etc.

Comment: If you're calling `useTestStore` at the top of your composable code then it is going to be called before your app has fully initialized.  That's not the usual error message you see when doing that but you don't show how exactly your composable works so maybe something else is affecting it. Usually composable files have a function you export and use elsewhere in your app.  **Call `useTestStore()` inside that function**.  The function itself doesn't run before the app is initialized so when it _does_ run it will work fine.